# Как получить то, что скрипт выводит на экран в виде переменной?

Tags: php

Есть скрипт (html.php), который генерит и выводит на экран некий html-код. (Если это вдруг важно, код выводится напрямую как html, а также через "echo". Внутри скрипта идут обращения к базе данных, к другим файлам, в общем, генерится контент).

Мне нужно получить сгенерированный этим скриптом html как переменную массива. То есть не выводить данные на экран, а засунуть в массив, типа что-то вроде:

$output ['html'] = *ЧТО_ТУТ_НАПИСАТЬ?* ("html.php")

Такое возможно в принципе или это мои фантазии?

Comment: можете перед началом скрипта включить буферизацию вывода, в конце скрипта скинуть то что в буфере в вашу переменную.

Comment: https://www.php.net/ob_start и далее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте функции буферизации вывода.
в самом простом варианте так:

```
ob_start();

echo "hello world!";

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();


var_dump($output);
```